# How to install sympy for Python 3.4

Tags: python, python3

I installed the Python scipy stack using the following command taken from [here](http://www.scipy.org/install.html)

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose
```

However, I can import `sympy` only in `Python 2.7.6` which is the default Python version when I type in `python` in the terminal. When I start `Python 3.4.0` by typing in `python3`, the `import sympy` statement throws the error

```
>>> import sympy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'sympy'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `pip3` (which is just normal `pip` but in system's Python3 packages). Normally I would suggest avoiding using pip for installing stuff globally but given there are no packages for this that could overwrite the files, there's nothing to lose.

It's quick and simple:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install sympy
```

Comment: Why using `pip` to install packages globally should be avoided?

Comment: For example if you have the `python-requests` package installed and then `sudo pip install requests`, it'll overwrite files that apt installed and then if apt updates, it'll overwrite those files and it turns into a big mushy mess. The two systems will likely be using different versions of the Requests library too. If you need your own Python environment (which you might, I do for Django development) use `virtualenv`.

Comment: ... Or `python3 -m venv` for Python 3

Answer (score 9):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later, Sympy Computer Algebra System in Python can be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-sympy
```

To install Sympy for Python 2.x in Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier run:

```
sudo apt install python-sympy
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a [backports](https://launchpad.net/~nschloe/+archive/ubuntu/sympy-backports) and a [nightly PPA](https://launchpad.net/~nschloe/+archive/ubuntu/sympy-nightly) with versions for all recent Ubuntu releases. Simply go

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nschloe/sympy-backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-sympy
```