# Unable to install sympy for Python3.8.6

Tags: python, pip

I attempted to install sympy on my workstation using the instructions in this related question:

[How to install sympy for Python 3.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576133/how-to-install-sympy-for-python-3-4)

i.e.

```
sudo pip3 install sympy
```

The installation completed without any error messages, but when I'm running python and try to import sympy, I get the following error. Evidently python cannot locate the sympy library, but I'm not sure why this would be the case

```
import sympy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
```

Comment: What OS & release are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: It is possible to have multiple versions of python-3 installed in parallel. It seems like somehow the package is installed into another one than you started.